# Does OptaPlanner have a "built-in" way to perform multi-unit score normalization?

Tags: drools, optaplanner, pareto-optimality

At the moment, my problem has four metrics.  Each of these measures something entirely different (each has different units, a different range, etc.) and each is weighted externally.  I am using Drools for scoring.

I only have only one score level (`SimpleLongScore`) and I have to find a way to appropriately combine the individual scores of these metrics onto one `long` value

The most significant problem at the moment is that the range of values for the metrics can be wildly different.

So if, for example, after a move the score of a metric with a small possible range improves by, say, 10%, that could be completely dwarfed by an alternate move which improves the metric with a larger range's score by only 1% because OptaPlanner only considers the actual score value rather than the possible range of values and how changes affect them proportionally (to my knowledge).

So, is there a way to handle this cleanly which is already part of OptaPlanner that I cannot find?

Is the only feasible solution to implement Pareto scoring?  Because that seems like a hack-y nightmare.

So far I have code/math to compute the best-possible and worst-possible scores for a metric that I access from within the Drools and then I can compute where in that range a move puts us, but this also feel quite hack-y and will cause issues with incremental scoring if we want to scale non-linearly within that range.

I keep coming back to thinking I should just just bite the bullet and implement Pareto scoring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `@ConstraintConfiguration` and `@ConstraintWeight` in the docs.

Also take a look at the chapter "explaning the score", which can exactly tell you which constraint had which score impact on the best solution found.

If, however, you *need* pareto optimization, so you *need* **multiple** best solutions that don't dominate each other, then know that OptaPlanner doesn't support that yet, but I know of 2 cases that implemented it in OptaPlanner by hacking `BestSolutionRecaller`.

That being said, 99% of the cases that think of pareto optimization, are 100% happy with `@ConstraintWeight` instead, because users don't want multiple best solutions (except during simulations), they just want one in production.

Comment: Thank you; apologies for the delay.  I do have a @ConstraintConfiguration class setup.  Users may set weights for each of the metrics and those are captured in the ConsConfig.  The current solution calculates worst/best possible scores and normalizes each score increment before being applied to the total.  The issue is that each metric may measure something different and without pareto/normalization, certain metrics will dominate scoring even if the changes aren't actually significant. For example, +1000 to metric A may not be better than +10 to metric B.

Comment: Sounds like you have a metric that scales differently that the other penalities. Square root might help there. See https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html